# Grouping the rows of a table in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the below table which has 2 columns.I need to write a query which will return 3 columns,the first 2 column should match the 2 columns present in the table and the 3rd column should group into n splits.
for example in this case I want to split into 4 groups.so 1st 4 rows should return 1 in column 3,2nd 4 rows should return 2, 3rd 4 rows should return 3 and finally last 3 rows(as there are in total 15 rows) should return 4.

```
DECLARE @NAMES TABLE ( [ID] INT IDENTITY, [NAME] VARCHAR(20) )   
INSERT INTO @NAMES SELECT 'NAME1' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'NAME2' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'NAME3' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'NAME4' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'NAME5' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'NAME6' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'NAME7' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'NAME8' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'NAME9' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'NAME10' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'NAME11' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'NAME12' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'NAME13' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'NAME14' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'NAME15'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try NTILE() function in SQL Server

```
select ID, Name, ntile(4) over (order by Name) from @Names
```

Comment: +1 - But note that you are re-sorting this data.  `Name1` and `Name10` will now be next to each other.

Comment: Yes, thank you for that, you can order by id if you do not want to do that

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select *,((ID-1)/4)+1 
from @NAMES
```

or

```
select *,(ROW_NUMBER() over (order by id)-1)/4+1
from @NAMES
```

## [SQL fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/5233)

Comment: Assumes that the identity column doesn't have gaps cause by reseeding the identity, failed inserts, deletes, etc.  It's a very poor assumption in any live database.